# Additional line in the Plotting

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, functions

I'm trying to plot a function, the problem is that the plot contains additional lines which originate from the solution itself, but at the same time removing the solutions will delete a whole portion of the graph
this is the code

```
t = 0.6366;
a = 1;
k = -1;
d = 7;

T[r_] = 1/(12 Pi r (r^2 + a k)^2) ((48 Pi r^6 P)/(d - 2) + 
     3 (d - 3) k r^4 + 3 (d - 5) r^2 k^2 a + (d - 7) a^2 k^3) - t

l = FullSimplify[NSolve[T[r] == 0, r]];
Length[l]
G[r_] = ((r^(d - 1))*
     P/(d - 1) + ((d - 2) (k^2 a^2 + 3 r^2 k a + 
         3 r^4) k r^(d - 7))/(48 Pi) - (r^(d - 
          7))/(48 Pi (r^2 + k a)^2) (r^4/(d - 2) + (2 k a r^2)/(d - 
          4) + (k^2 a^2)/(d - 6))*(48 Pi P r^6 + (d - 
          2) (3 k (d - 3) r^4 + 3 k^2 a (d - 5) r^2 + 
          a^2 k^3 (d - 7))));

Plot[G[r] /. #, {P, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}] & /@ l
Plot[G[r] /. l[[{1, 2, 3}]], {P, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-1, -0}}, 
 PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

this is what I get

[image]

and this is what I should get (only the blue plot)

[image]

the same problem happens with the yellow plot where tc=1/(2Pi) where in my case two additional lines appear, this is the yellow plot

[image]

Please if you have any idea about this problem I will appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: How do you obtain the yellow plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra line is due to a jump discontinuity in the value of `G[r]`, which switches from positive to negative right before that jump. One way to avoid that portion is to include more constraints in `Solve`.

That triggers complaints from Solve about using machine-precision numbers, so I have re-defined `t` as arbitrary-precision below:

```
t = 6366/10000;

(* the following are the same as your definitions *)
a = 1; k = -1; d = 7;

T[r_] = 1/(12 Pi r (r^2 + a k)^2) ((48 Pi r^6 P)/(d - 2) + 
     3 (d - 3) k r^4 + 3 (d - 5) r^2 k^2 a + (d - 7) a^2 k^3) - t

G[r_] = ((r^(d - 1))*
     P/(d - 1) + ((d - 2) (k^2 a^2 + 3 r^2 k a + 
         3 r^4) k r^(d - 7))/(48 Pi) - (r^(d - 
          7))/(48 Pi (r^2 + k a)^2) (r^4/(d - 2) + (2 k a r^2)/(d - 
          4) + (k^2 a^2)/(d - 6))*(48 Pi P r^6 + (d - 
          2) (3 k (d - 3) r^4 + 3 k^2 a (d - 5) r^2 + 
          a^2 k^3 (d - 7))));
```

Then use `Solve` to obtain only real solutions, and with the added constraint that $r>0$ (avoid the `FullSimplify`: it doesn't seem to do much here):

```
l = Solve[{T[r] == 0, r > 0}, r, Reals]
```

[image: the output of Solve contains three solutions, expressed as Root objects]

As you can see, `Solve` already selected out the last two solutions from your unconstrained results, which are complex.

Now plot the three in separate colors, to highlight where each portion of your graph comes from:

```
Plot[Evaluate[G[r] / .l], {P, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}]
```

[image: plot of three solutions, in separate colors. This no longer has the offending vertical portion]

If you want them all in the same color, add e.g. `PlotStyle -> Blue` in the above plotting expression.

Comment: Thank you Mr. MacroB, I appreciate your explanation and solution.

Answer (score 1):

You must restrict the region of "P" and only plot the piece you want. However, this will restrict the x-axis. To prevent this you need `PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, -0}}`:

```
Plot[G[r] /. l[[{1, 2, 3}]], {P, 0.2, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, -0}}, PlotStyle -> Blue]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mr. Daniel for your answer i appreciate it.